# How can I make child elements of flex layout resize according to the space they have?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've built this web app, that scrambles letters to create words. All letters are layed in a horizontal flex. Everything works fine, until you add many letters' and at that point the word overflows the width of the scree nwhich gives for a poor user experience.

Thing is, how can I size every letter in this layout to be the available width it can get, and resize when letters are added/removed?
The main issue, is that I can't set it as columns in a grid layout because the amount of columns would keep changing.

This is my code right now for the parent word component:

```
.current-word{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Then its child elements are all letters components, and this is their layout. I had to define a width to the element, becuse if I wasn't it was fairly wide because it is an input field (users can change letters, so had to use an inout field):

```
.letter {
  width: 7rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  &__input {
    border: none;
    max-width: 7rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: var(--font-main-bold);
    font-size: 7rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      font-size: 4rem;
    }
  }
}
```

I feel like actually seeing what I've built might explain it much better but I'm not sure if it breaks any rules to post a link. If it isn't I'd appreciate if someone would let me know and I'll post it.